# Unable To Validate Confirm Password Field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to validate the various fields in my form and I have a problem with my JavaScript. When a user leaves focus on the confirm password field, it should check to see if the password field is valid (satisfies all requirements) and if it does, check to see if the passwords match. If both of those are true return true. My problem is that I keep receiving the error saying that my password is not valid regardless if it is fine or not. The problem is with the validateConfirmPassword() function. I believe it's a simple mistake but I can't seem to figure it out. Note: I haven't finished writing all of the javascript to validate all of the fields so it will throw some errors saying some elements are not found.

Javascript:

```
//input fields

const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
const company = document.getElementById('company');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const address = document.getElementById('address');
const address2 = document.getElementById('address2');
const city = document.getElementById('city');
const state = document.getElementById('state');
const zip = document.getElementById('zip');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const cell = document.getElementById('cell');
const musicianType = document.getElementById('musicianType');
const musicianType2 = document.getElementById('musicianType2');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const cnfPassword = document.getElementById('cnfPassword');
const securityQuestion = document.getElementById('securityQuestion');
const securityAnswer = document.getElementById('securityAnswer');
const pin = document.getElementById('pin');
const churchAffiliation1 = document.getElementById('churchAffiliation1');
const churchAffiliation2 = document.getElementById('churchAffiliation2');
const churchAffiliation3 = document.getElementById('churchAffiliation3');
const churchAffiliation4 = document.getElementById('churchAffiliation4');

//form

const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');


//validation colors
const green = '#4CAF50';
const red = '#F44336';

// validators

function validateFirstName() {
    //check if it is empty
    if (checkIfEmpty(firstName)) return;

    //check if it only has letters
    if (!checkIfOnlyLetters(firstName)) return;
    return true;
}

function validateLastName() {
    //check if it is empty
    if (checkIfEmpty(lastName)) return;

    //check if it only has letters
    if (!checkIfOnlyLetters(lastName)) return;
    return true;
}

function validatePassword() {
    //check if it is empty
    if (checkIfEmpty(password)) return;
    // Must be a certain length
    if (!meetLength(password, 8, 20)) return;
    // check password against character set
    // 1 - a
    // 2 - A
    // 3 - A  a  1
    // 4 - A  a  1  @
    if (!containsCharacters(password, 4)) return;

    return true;
}

function validateConfirmPassword() {
    if (password.className !== 'valid') {
        setInvalid(cnfPassword, `Password must be valid`);
        return;
    }
    // check if passwords matched
    if (password.value !== cnfPassword.value) {
        setInvalid(cnfPassword, `Passwords must match`);
        return;
    } else {
        setValid(cnfPassword);
        
    }
    return true;
}
//Utility functions

function checkIfEmpty(field) {
    if (isEmpty(field.value.trim())) {
        //set field invalid
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must not be empty`);
        return true;
    } else {
        //set field valid
        setValid(field);
        return false;
    }
}


function isEmpty(value) {
    if (value === '') return true
    return false;
}

function setInvalid(field, message) {
    field.className = 'form-control'
    field.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = message;
    field.nextElementSibling.style.color = red;
}

function setValid(field) {
    field.className = 'form-control'
    field.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = '';
    field.nextElementSibling.style.color = green;
}

function checkIfOnlyLetters(field) {
    if (/[a-zAZ ]+$/.test(field.value)) {
        setValid(field);
        return true;
    } else {
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must contain only letters`)
        return false;
    }
}

function meetLength(field, minLength, maxLength) {
    if (field.value.length >= minLength && field.value.length) {
        setValid(field);
        return true;
    } else if (field.value.length < minLength) {
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must be at least ${minLength} characters long`);
        return false;
    } else {
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must not be longer than ${maxLength} characters`);
        return false;
    }

}

function containsCharacters(field, code) {
    let regEx;
    switch (code) {

        case 1:
            //letters
            regEx = /(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/;
            return matchWithRegEx(regEx, field, `Must contain at least 1 letter`);
        case 2:
            // letters and numbers
            regEx = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/;
            return matchWithRegEx(regEx, field, `Must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number`);
        case 3:
            //lowercase, uppercase and number
            regEx = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/;
            return matchWithRegEx(regEx, field, `Must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase number, and 1 number`);
        case 4:
            //uppercase, lowercase, number and symbol
            regEx = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)/;
            return matchWithRegEx(regEx, field, `Must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase number, 1 number and 1 symbol`);

        default:
            false;
    }
}

function matchWithRegEx(regEx, field, message) {
    if (field.value.match(regEx)) {
        setValid(field);
        return true;
    } else {
        setInvalid(field, message);
        return false
    }
}
```

Form markup:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Account Security</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                        <input maxlength="20" type="password" required class="form-control" name="Password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onfocusout="validatePassword()"/>
                        <ul class="input-requirements">
                            <li>Must be 8-20 characters long</li>
                            <li>Must contain at least 1 number</li>
                            <li>Must contain at least 1 uppercase letter</li>
                            <li>Must contain at least 1 lowercase letter </li>
                            <li>Must contain a special character (e.g. ! ; # * %)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="Confirm Password" id="cnfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" onfocusout="validateConfirmPassword()"/>
                        <small class="form-text"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Security Question</label>
                        <select name="Security Question" id="securityQuestion" required class="form-control" onfocusout="validateSecurityQuestion()">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            @{
                                foreach (var secretquestion in Model.securityquestions)
                                {
                                    <option value="@secretquestion.id">@secretquestion.Question</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                        <small class="form-text"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Security Answer</label>
                        <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="Security Answer" id="securityAnswer" placeholder="Confirm Password" onfocusout="validateSecurityAnswer()"/>
                        <small class="form-text"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">Account PIN</label>
                        <input maxlength="6" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="Pin" id="pin" placeholder="PIN" onfocusout="validatePin()"/>
                        <small class="form-text"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have `if (password.className !== 'valid')` but nothing ever sets that class on the `password` input.

Comment: Also, since elements can have multiple classes, you shouldn't compare with `className`, since that contains *all* the classes. You should use `if (password.classList.contains('valid'))`

Comment: You have a function named `setValid()` whose name sounds like it should be adding that class. But it doesn't, it sets the `form-control` class.

Comment: Why does it do that, since the inputs already have that class?

Comment: It should use `field.classList.add('valid')`